# Matlab optimtool: setting different bounds to different integer variable indices

Tags: matlab, integer, genetic-algorithm

I can define which of my input variables should be integer in the integer variable indices box. I can also set bounds for input variables. But,
what if different integer variables should comply with different upper/lower bounds?

Answer (score 0):

Answer found: 
In Optimtool, in Constraints/Bounds you can set the applicable lower and upper bounds (use an expression of the type e.g [lb1,lb2,...] for every input variable)